# Read from json and write back while preserving original formatting in java

Tags: java, json

I am trying to read a json file and update a specific field. I am able to get to the proper nested location, but when I save it back after update, I get lots of "\r\n" instead of the original formatting.
I have tried using two approaches for reading:

```
   private LinkedHashMap get3rdJsonAsMap() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();//.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        LinkedHashMap json = null;
        try {
            json = (LinkedHashMap)objectMapper.readValue(new File(this.mono3rdJsonPath), Object.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return json;
    }
```

and with:

```
  private JsonNode get3rdJsonAsNode() {
    objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();//.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    JsonNode json = null;
    try {
        json = objectMapper.readTree(new File(this.mono3rdJsonPath));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return json;
}
```

I am writing with this:

```
 private void writeProvisionAsObject(Object json) {
        ObjectWriter writer = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        String updatedJsonString;
        try {
            updatedJsonString = writer.writeValueAsString(json);
            // Write the updated JSON string back to the JSON file
            objectMapper.writeValue(new File(this.filePath), updatedJsonString);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Also I've heard of JsonTokenizer but I've read that in order to preserve original formatting, I must append each line manually, which I am trying to avoid.

How can I achieve preserving orginal formating?

Comment: Can't you just agree on a fixed json formatting standard of a tool of your choice, apply this once to your source once and then apply it again after modifying the json source?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to this with Jackson.  Jackson's purpose to serialize/deserialize from/to objects and necessarily "formatting" is lost.

I recommend you look at a library like [Streamflyer](https://github.com/rwitzel/streamflyer) allows you to modify a JSON **stream** by matching on a Regex and replacing matches as the stream passes through the processor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this seems like a manual parsing solution, which is what I am trying to avoid

Answer (score 0):

Jackson knows about [JsonLocation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonLocation.html). A parser keeps track of which content is being parsed at which location. You could use this information to restore a lot of formatting like whitespace at start of lines or even whitespace between array elements.

But extending this to also preserve line breaks (when needing to differentiate between line windows and linux line breaks for example) needs extensive customization in the parser and possibly `JsonLocation` too. This might be possible but its questionalbe if its worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

With bard and Gson I've come up with this:

```
 public void updateVersion(String version){
    JsonElement originalJsonObject = getRootElement();
    ((JsonObject)((JsonObject)((JsonObject)originalJsonObject).get("streams")).get("provision2")).addProperty("version", version);
    String jsonText = gson.toJson(originalJsonObject);
    try {
        writeFile(jsonText); // Write to original location
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private JsonElement getRootElement() {
    gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    String jsonInput = null;
    try {
        jsonInput = readFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return gson.fromJson(jsonInput, JsonElement.class);
}

private String readFile() throws IOException {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(this.mono3rdJsonPath);
    StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();
    int read;
    while ((read = reader.read()) != -1) {
        fileContent.append((char) read);
    }
    reader.close();
    return fileContent.toString();
}

private void writeFile(String fileContent) throws IOException {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(this.mono3rdJsonPath);
    writer.write(fileContent);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

The only thing left is a bit of extra spaces that at the begining of each row, and a problem with text wrapped in ' '
Original json:

```
 {
    "first": {
        
    },
"_comment1": " entries of 'includeDirs'",
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "first": {},
  "_comment1": " entries of \u0027includeDirs\u0027 ",
}
```